# What's the difference between "moderators" and "moderation"?

Tags: discussion, tag-management, meta

What's the difference between these two tags - [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) and [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation)? Should these two tags be merged?

Comment: To me the tag summaries suggest that "moderators" concerns the diamond moderators, while "moderation" is more broadly applicable to actions taken in the course of Community moderation.  [At Stack Exchange, we believe moderation starts with the community itself,](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: @hardmath that'd make a good answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an emphasis in the Stack Exchange philosophy on [Community moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160960/what-is-community-moderation-and-what-can-i-do-to-help), and in my thought having distinct tags for "moderators" and "moderation" reflects this philosophy.

As noted in [the tag summary for **moderators**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderators), it is for:

> Questions about diamond (♦) moderators, their powers, and actions they have taken.

The Help Center [describes moderators](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) as "human exception handlers, there to deal with those exceptional conditions that could otherwise disrupt the community."

But the visibility of diamond moderators (elected on a site-basis), however confidential much of their activity, does not diminish the responsibility of users to perform [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) actions commensurate with reputation/privilege levels.

As outlined in Jeff Atwood's [A Theory of Moderation (2009)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/), at varying levels of reputation users can:

- flag posts (15 pts)
- review "first" posts (500 pts)
- edit any question or answer (2000 pts)
- cast open and close votes (3000 pts)
- cast delete and undelete votes on questions (10,000 pts)
- "protect" questions (15,000 pts)
- cast delete votes on negatively voted answers (20,000 pts)

See the [schedule of privileges and reputation levels](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), esp. the entries annotated as Moderation.